# Why does this segfault in C?

Tags: c

I can't figure out why this tiny C program segfaults:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int in = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Input %d\n",in);

    int *n = (int *)malloc(in);
    int j;

    for (j=0;j<in;j++)
        n[j] = j;

    printf("Sanity check...\n");

    char *c = (char *)malloc(1024*1024*20);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20*1024*1024;i++)
        c[i] = i;

    printf("No segfault. Yay!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

> $ gcc -O0 test.c -o run

Output:

> $ ./run 1000
>
> $ Input 1000
>
> $ Sanity check...
>
> $ [1]     17529 Segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./run 1000

Now if I move one of the for-loops down like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int in = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Input %d\n",in);

    int *n = (int *)malloc(in);
    int j;

    printf("Sanity check...\n");

    char *c = (char *)malloc(1024*1024*20);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20*1024*1024;i++)
        c[i] = i;

    printf("No segfault. Yay!\n");

    for (j=0;j<in;j++)
        n[j] = j;
    
    return 0;
}
```

everything works.. same compilation step, this is the output:

> $ ./run 1000
>
> $ Input 1000
>
> $ Sanity check...
>
> $ No segfault. Yay!

Reason why I'm doing a large 20MB malloc is to try and remove cache effects from the code I am profiling. It feels like both implementations should work, but the first one segfaults when malloc-ing the 20MB array. Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
int in = atoi(argv[1]);
int *n = (int *)malloc(in);
```

You're allocating `in` bytes, not `in` integers.  Try:

```
malloc(sizeof(int) * in);
```

Your second allocation works because `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: Also, the casting of `malloc` is rather discouraged.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Why is the casting of malloc discouraged? You cannot belittle valid answers without a valid explanation

Comment: I do not belittle the answer - this answer corrects the mistake so there is no segmentation fault anymore. It does respond to the question. My side remark, is that the code you write should be as type-independent as possible - which means avoiding unnecessary casts. The cast here with `malloc` would be implicit anyway, so you can let the compiler do it without any problems.;)

Answer (score 5):

This statement

```
int *n = (int *)malloc(in);
```

is wrong.

I think you mean

```
int *n = (int *)malloc(in * sizeof( int ) );
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've made the changes and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
given the posted code,
lets just run down the reasons it seg faults.

my comments are interspersed with the code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// argc is not used, so the compiler will raise a warning
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // the value of argc was not checked to assure a parameter is present
    // so a 'usage' message was not output when no parameter is present
    // or too many parameters are present
    // note: 'in' is (IMO) a poor name for a local variable
    int in = atoi(argv[1]);
    // missing check to assure the value if 'in' is greater than 0
    // and handling the error when the value is <= 0

    printf("Input %d\n",in);

    // in C, the returned value from calls to malloc(), and family,
    //       should not be cast
    // the returned value is (per the definition of 'n')
    // to be a pointer to an array of int's
    // which should be written as:
    // int *n = malloc( in * sizeof int );
    // the returned value from malloc(), and family of functions,
    //     needs to always be checked (!= NULL)
    //     to assure the operation was successful
    int *n = (int *)malloc(in);
    int j;

    // because the malloc call did not ask for a memory allocation
    // of 'in' int's, so this code block corrupts the heap
    // by writing past the end of the allocated memory
    for (j=0;j<in;j++)
        n[j] = j;

    printf("Sanity check...\n");

    // in C, the returned value from calls to malloc(), and family of functions,
    //       should not be cast
    // the returned value needs to be checked (!= NULL) to assure the operation
    //       was successful
    // the calculated value: 1024*1024*20 should be calculated by the
    //       compiler, not repeatedly at run time.
    //       so insert 'const int twentyMillion = 1024*1024*20;'
    //       at beginning of program
    char *c = (char *)malloc(1024*1024*20);
    int i;

    // to avoid repeatedly calculating the 20million value, use a const (as above)
    // so this line would be: for ( i=0; i<twentyMillion; i++ )
    for (i=0; i<20*1024*1024;i++)
        // the value of 'i' will massively exceed the value that can be kept in a char
        //  I.E. 255 so this loses data
        //  suggest replacing following line with: j = i%256;  c[i] = j;
        // to make it obvious what is going on
        c[i] = i;

    printf("No segfault. Yay!\n");

    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Thanks! I wrote this tiny program on the side just for testing. It represents the flow of what I'm actually writing, in order to figure out where and why the segfaults are occuring without having to deal with all the other complexity around the "production" code. The formatting stuff that you mentioned (e.g. checking argc value and handling errors) is handled in the actual application I'm writing -- I stupidly overlooked the malloc for the int array, and learnt about not typecasting mallocs from this. So, thanks for your inputs!